# Geb Test DOM Element Exists And Then Is Removed On Next Page Load

Tags: gradle, spock, geb

I'm pretty new to Geb, but I'm facing an odd issue that the docs don't seem to address.  I have a pretty simple scenario to test:  log in as admin, open applications, verify that an 'apply' button appears on the home page.  Then close applications and verify that the button is gone from the home page.  I can perform this test manually with success and there is nothing on the server side (cache wise) preventing this from succeeding but when I run the test via Gradle it fails because the button is still being shown on the home page after the 'close' test.  Note that the test also verifies that the config was saved with the proper value.

Here's my test code:

```
def "can open applications"(){
    when:
    to ManageConfigPage

    and:
    configFormModule.toggleApplications(true)

    then:
    at ManageConfigPage
    assert $('#messages').text() == "Config successfully updated"
    assert $('td', text: 'config.application_closed').closest('tr').find('input').value() == "0"
    then:
    to HomePage
    assert applyButton
}


def "can close applications"(){
    when:
    to ManageConfigPage

    and:
    configFormModule.toggleApplications(false)

    then:
    at ManageConfigPage
    assert $('#messages').text() == "Config successfully updated"
    assert $('td', text: 'config.application_closed').closest('tr').find('input').value() == "1"
    then:
    to HomePage
    assert !applyButton
}
```

Here's the applyButton content definition:

```
applyButton(cache: false, required: false){ $('#apply_button') }
```

I also tried using the selector directly in the test instead of inside a content definition and that did not work either.

So what's going on here?  Is the home page being cached in it's entirety? If so, how do I prevent or refresh it?  This seems like Geb 101 but the manual doesn't really address this issue.

Edit:  adding the test result for completeness:

Condition not satisfied:

!applyButton
||
|applyButton - SimplePageContent (owner: HomePage, args: [], value: null)
false

```
at AdminSpec.can close applications(AdminSpec.groovy:59)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the button element not included in the html or is is simply hidden? If it's hidden then you will need to check that it's not displayed:

```
!applyButton.displayed
```

Comment: I added a sleep(5000) before moving to that page and it works as expected.  That shouldn't be necessary, but it works.